# GraalVM native JavaFX application visual bugs

Tags: linux, javafx, java-17, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I have created a new GraalVM + JavaFX project with simple interface, but instead of this:

[image]

I can see only this:

[image]

I have compiled my project with/on:

- Solus OS (Linux) with kernel 6.1.5
- Java 17 provided by GraalVM SDK (below)
- [GraalVM](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases) v22.1.0.1 redistributed by Gluon
- Using [GluonFX Maven Plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin) v1.0.16

You can easily reproduce it:

1. Clone my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/SoKnight/graalvm-sandbox) with all project related code
2. Download GraalVM release for your host system
3. Install (unpack) it anywhere and change path to SDK in `pom.xml` (`graalvm.home` property)
4. Just run `mvn clean install` to run metadata collecting agent, build native image and run it

Comment: What do you see in the logs for `mvn gluonfx:nativerun` ?

Comment: @JoséPereda yes, i did. I can loss something important, what I should to find there?

Comment: If there are no exceptions there, try running with `-Dprism.verbose=true` .

Comment: This looks like a resource loading problem to me. The css and the font seem to be missing somehow. That's what I would check first.

Comment: @JoséPereda Prism logging is looking fine, no exceptions or `error` tagged messages.

@mipa I check that, but there are no CSS resource used, only inline styles. Font is loaded correctly because there are no any errors like NPE or another resource loading exception. I also tried to use default font (without any custom), but there are no button text displayed anyway.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your project runs fine for me on macOS. Maybe you can try to catch some possible hidden exception, adding `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }` to the content of your  `start()` method.

Comment: @JoséPereda thank you for testing of this code on MacOS, but the problem still unresolved for Linux hosts :(

All this time I have test native compilation of this project using Liberica Native Image Kit (Java 17) and it works fine in case when the binary is already opened and I trying to run second app process using same binary file.

Video example: https://youtu.be/gCOBO3Lfgvc

Seems that problem cause is video driver OR desktop environment OR windows manager (X11)

Comment: Can you check with `ldd` if the native binary is missing any package or library?

Comment: One other thing you can try is enabling sw rendering in the plugin’s configuration and set `-Dprism.order=sw`, then build and test.

Comment: `-Dprism.order=sw` solved a similar issue in Linux for me (rendering ok but no text at all shown) in a program I am working on, so thanks! Also, unlike the software renderer, the default one tends to slow down when loading a lot of images, so I suspect there is one bug or two lurking around...

Answer (score 1):

During all that day I have tested native AOT compilation of this test project.
Binaries is working fine on **Windows and Mac OS hosts**, but **not at all Linux hosts**, and it's so sad :(

I will use the next 'partially native' app distribution solution:

- Linux: **app-image** (jlink) + **launch4j**.
- Mac OS: **native-image** using Liberica NIK.
- Windows: **native-image** using Liberica NIK.

Thanks a lot to [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%c3%a9-pereda) for any help and instant answers.